# How to set Content Type='text/html; charset=utf-8' in asp.net 401 page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to set content type to 'text/html; charset=utf8' for asp.net default error pages (401). I tried overriding it in beginrequest event in global.asax and also tried writing http module for this one but still it always return only 'text/hrml' any suggestions how i can do it

[image]

Comment: Is that 401 a file you're serving? What does your httperrors section look like in the system.webserver section of your web.config?

Comment: @rene it works absolutly fine when I set Custom Error Mode to off, but when I turn custom error mode on then it happens.